# Assigning Random Numbers to Variables Without Duplicates in Python

Tags: python, variables, random, variable-assignment

I am new to Python and need help regarding assigning numbers to variables. How would I assign a random number from 0 to 9 to the variables "a" through "j" so that each variable gets a random number with no duplicates? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should always include that with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to return a dictionary where the letters have been randomly mapped to numbers as well. It's a bit longer than other answers, but maybe easier for a beginner to follow the logic

```
import random

numbers_list = []
combined = {}
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
while True:
    number = random.randint(0, 9)
    if number in numbers_list:
        pass
    else:
        numbers_list.append(number)
        combined.update({alphabet.pop(): number})
    if len(numbers_list) == 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
import random

vals = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(vals)
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = vals
```

Comment: The best way, though making many variables is ill-advised. Short and clear; it's a shame someone downvoted it.

Comment: I agree with the many variable thing, but it's OP's request... So to OP: you probably want to restructure your code to use `vals[x]` directly rather than defining 10 variables.

Comment: Or maybe `dict(zip('abcdefg', vals))` if you wanted to call them by name.

Comment: Do you know how I would make it so that the program does not repeat the same assignments to all of the variables again? A number could be assigned to the same variable again, however just not all ten numbers to the same variable.

Comment: I don't understand, please clarify exactly (example?) what's not satisfying you with my answer.